# How to delete chosen row on context menu?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contextmenu

I want to delete an sqlite db record when I choose a delete menu item from a context menu.
I created a context menu and it is working, but I can't delete the db row. Is there any way to delete the record? What shall I do?

```
public void deleteItem(dbItem item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(TABLE_ITEMS, items_id + " = ?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

    int menuitemindex = item.getItemId();


    if(item.getItemId()==0)
    {
        //code for send text
    } 
    else if(item.getItemId()==1) // Delete menu item
    {
       //  db.deleteItem(item2);
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);    
 }
```

How can I use my **deleteItem()** procedure on context menu section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution after 12 days later :)

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

    int menuitemindex = item.getItemId();


    if(menuitemindex == 0)
    {
        //code for send text
    } 
    else if(menuitemindex == 1)
    {           
        dbItem silinen = adapter.getItem(info.position);      
        adapter.remove(silinen);            
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        db.deleteItem(silinen, getApplicationContext());        
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);    
 }
```

And delete procedure:

```
public void deleteItem(dbItem item, Context context) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {

      db.delete(TABLE_ITEMS, items_id + " = ?",
              new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getID())});

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
      Log.e("insert",e.getMessage());
    }


    Toast.makeText(context, "Item succesfully deleted. Name: "+ item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    db.close();        

}
```

Comment: Where does `adapter` come from?